# Data Binding tutorials using Microsoft Expression Blend4 for WPF application

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, data-binding

I am new to to Microsoft Expression Blend 4 and WPF. I am not finding tutorials about Data Binding for XML and also for DBs. If you have any resources, please post the it.

Thanks and regards
Harsha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My biggest recommendation is looking into Entity Framework.

If you've already got your database designed, you can auto generate code that lets you access and databind to your db. You can enable lazy loading so data doesn't get loaded from the database until you first access that data. You modify your data all you like (and it does it in memory), then you can choose when to persist those changes to the db by calling a Save() method, or you could cancel the changes you've made and revert them back to what was in the db before you made changes.

It's pretty slick and I definately recommend giving it a try.

I might suggest looking at a basic tutorial and a sample project to see what all you can do.

Here's a starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx